# Translating linguistic terminology into Russian

Tags: терминология, лингвистика

I want to translate some applied linguistic (and others uncommon) words from Italian to Russian which I didn't find on Internet:

1. *Pragmatic annotation*
2. *Elicited* from this phrase "*We have chosen to analyze the questioning strategy by comparing the data of two types of task oriented dialogues. The first one is **elicited** through the "Map Task" technique and another with the "Difference test" technique.*"

**elicited** means extraction of the dialogue (with one of the two techniques)

3. *idiosyncratic* from this phrase: *"Each of us adopts strategies based on **idiosyncratic** characteristics and on the basis of social, cultural and situational factors."*

**idiosyncratic** : The term can also be applied to symbols or words. Idiosyncratic symbols mean one thing for a particular person, as a blade could mean war, but to someone else, it could symbolize a surgery.

Thanks to those who will answer me

Answer (score 2):

1. Pragmatic annotation = Прагматическая аннотация
2. Data elicited through... = Данные, полученные посредством... (followed by Genitive)
3. idiosyncratic = [идиосинкратический](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9)

Comment: About idiosyncratic I found this translation идиосинкретический 
 from this site https://translate.academic.ru/idiosyncratic/en/xx/

Comment: Yes, идиосинкретический might be preferred in linguistics since it is tagged "лингвистика" on the page you linked to. Here is a more specific link: https://translate.academic.ru/idiosyncratic/en/ru/

Comment: However, in terms of Google hits, идиосинкратический is 10x more likely. I would go with it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Since 'annotation' [refers to](http://www.lrec-conf.org/proceedings/lrec2014/summaries/323.html) 'a pragmatic meaning in spoken text', and since '' is usually used in Russian academic language as a term for 'summary', I believe the terms '***прагматическая атрибуция***' or '***прагматическая дистрибуция***' would work better.
2. In this context the word *elicited* can also be rendered by a noun ***выдержка***, e. g. 'The first one is elicited through the... ' = "***Первое - выдержка, полученная посредством***..."